# How to work different domain user same collection at TFS

Tags: tfs, permissions, dns

We use the internal Team Foundation Server(TFS) for our in-house software projects at our data-center. Now we want to use the same TFS at outsource projects, too. However we don't add the outsource users to domain(AD). So I created local user account in TFS server for outsource users. Then local user take error as below.

TFS login error

[image]

When I had been added new domain user, I didn' get this error.
Don't we use domain user and local user together at TFS?

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507(v=vs.100).aspx#Team Foundation Clients in a Domain and Team Foundation Server in a Workgroup and make sure that the user meet the requirement mentioned in it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use domain user and local user together at TFS, for your case please make sure the local user have granted the permission to access the tfs.

Managing user access to TFS is much easier using groups, not individual users.
To add users who will contribute fully to this project, choose **Contributors**. By default, the team group created when you created the project is included as a member of the **Contributors** group, so you could choose to add the new local user as a member of the team instead, and the user would automatically inherit Contributor permissions.
[Please see the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQLZS.png)

Comment: Thank you for your interesting. I tried to add as new local user but result is same(to screenshot: https://puu.sh/tCcSg/5760fbe9d0.PNG). By the way your link is not working

Comment: @Gökhan K Can you navigate to the project via web portal with the local user? If yes, it certainly can be connected via VS. I checked again and it works for me. Please clean caches or change to another windows account then start VS to try it again, make sure enter the correct credentials (local user) when start the VS. Screenshot updated.